# Adding multiple values in one column

Tags: c#, mysql

My problem is that when I click the save button only the value of `txtEmail1` will be saved in the `email` column.

```
MySqlCommand cmd;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( @Id,@email)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail1.Text + "" + txtEmail2.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Are you sure? That should work in my opinion. What are the values of `txtEmail1.Text`, `txtEmail2.Text` and `txtId.Text` exactly?  Are they could contain some special characters? And `+ "" +` is useless here.

Comment: email is varchar? And if so what size?

Comment: If this code is not working. try it another way, Both textbox value are store in one string variable and pass it.

Comment: are you sure `txtEmail2.Text` is not empty?

Comment: aw sorry for my mistake... what I want to happen is that these 2 values from the txtEmail1 and txtEmail2 will be added in different rows but in the same column because what happened is that they were saved in the same row

Comment: @davz_11 : Like I said, store both textbox value in one string variable or use string.Concat operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
string[] email = new string[2];
email[0] = txtEmail1.Text;
email[1] = txtEmail2.Text;

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
    {
      MySqlCommand cmd;
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( @Id,@email)";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email[i]);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
    }
```

Comment: it only adds the txtEmail1 and i dont know why... tnx by the way for the effort

Comment: still the same brother... i doubled check the textbox variables and they were correct